# Accept integer on my data types in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, types

Lets say my,

```
1. number must only accept integer and (3 integer)?
2. address must only accept 10 characters?
3. phone integer only with a maximum of 13?
```

What are the data types I'm going to use on them? and how can I managed the max and min integer value on php using mysql database.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sounds like homework and should be done by op itself

Comment: Typically you would handle data validation in application code. Just because a value only accepts integers, that doesn't make it an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP function "filter_var" with "FILTER_VALIDATE_INT" flag and options (min_rage, max_range).

You have an example, [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_int.asp).